# Docker swarm nodes on private networks?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Is there theoretically anyway to connect nodes to a Docker swarm if they are on a private network and don't have a public IP? The swarm host has a public IP, and the nodes can access it as well as a discovery service just fine, but they themselves are on private networks over which I have no control. So is this possible?

Comment: If they're on the same private network then fine. If the nodes cannot communicate with each other then it's my understanding that the new networking feature in Docker 1.9 will not work.

Comment: Thanks, yea the situation is that all of the nodes are on different private networks. But I dont actually need networking in between them. I just need the master to be able to communicate with them as usual. Does that mean its possible, and if so do you have any resources to point me to?

Comment: If all you require is load placement or scheduling, I would recommend using Apache Mesos instead. I think you'll discover it's a lot more robust and mature compared to Docker Swarm and the Mesos master will provide you with a console for monitoring the status of your slave nodes. Whatever solution you choose I do suspect you'll bump into networking, it's inevitable that you'll want to wire your docker hosts together.

Answer (score 0):

I this situation you ether tunnel the requests or use weave for creating the Virtual Private network.